# Matter protocol with Arduino Mega/Giga

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, home-automation

I would like to try matter protocol with Arduino mega or Arduino giga.

But I don't find any sample or library. I have only found libraries compatibles with ESP32.

Do you know how I can work with matter protocol on an Arduino Mega or Giga ?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? "_Why_" something is the way it is usually cannot be answered, and the probable reason will not help you, I'm afraid. It might be as simple as "Because the authors did not make it for those Arduino models." So please [edit] your question and ask what you really want to know.

Comment: Sorry, i have edit my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If [this is the source code repository for the ESP32 Matter project](https://github.com/Yacubane/esp32-arduino-matter), then this statement from the README file found there:

> Make sure that ESP32 board version is 2.0.14. This is crucial, because
> this library contains pre-compiled files.

...would infer that not all the source code is available. It follows that the application can not be ported to a different processor.

Comment: Apparently it is an 'open' standard per wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_(standard) so theoretically one could write their own source with enough effort... Not that there aren't 'open' standards where just about every implementation is proprietary and fails to be compatible with items of other (or even the same) proprietor(s).